# abstractly define field that contains an instance of the class

Tags: c#, constructor, static, abstract

I have an abstract class

```
abstract class ClassA
{
}
```

and some inheriting, non-abstract classes

```
class ClassB : ClassA
{
}

class ClassC : ClassA
{
}
```

For all inheriting classes I want to have a static field called "Instance" which is an instance of the class, created by the parameterless constructor. One way of defining that is this:

```
class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public static ClassA Instance = new ClassB();
}

class ClassC : ClassA
{
    public static ClassA Instance = new ClassC();
}
```

But in order to minimize redundancy, I want to define this field inside `ClassA`. How do I do that? Is there some construct like below (pseudocode)?

```
abstract class ClassA
{
    public static readonly ClassA Instance = CallConstructorOfActualClass();
}
```

---

Why I need this: Because I want to simulate abstract static getters. For each class I want to store some number which should behave statically (=no class instance needed), but different per class (e.g. `ClassB` has 2, `ClassC` has 5). Since that does not work, I would make an abstract (nonstatic) getter in `ClassA` and always have a static `Instance` field for any inheriting (non-abstract) class from which I can call that getter.

Comment: Why not just have an abstract method on ClassA that returns an int, then define it in each derived class to return whatever int you want for each class?

Comment: Try this: `abstract class ClassA<TDerived> where TDerived : ClassA<TDerived>, new() { public static readonly TDerived Instance = new TDerived(); }`